# A system of $m$ linear equations and $n$ variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a system of $m$ linear equations and $n$ variables ?

- If $m<n$, then all such systems have a solution.
- If $m>n$, then none of these systems has a solution.
- If $m=n$, then there exists a system which has a solution.

---

> How can I Prove/Disprove above statements ? Any Examples ?

Comment: Let $n=3$. If $m=2$ we could have the system $a+b+c = 2, a+b+c = -1$.
Note: I'm not sure if this is allowed but if it is, it is a counter example to your first and 3rd point. A counter example to your 2nd point would be to have some equations being multiples of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $m=2<n=3$: No,
   $$
   \cases{x+y+z=0\\x+y+z=1}
   $$
   has no solution.
2. $m=2>n=1$: no, 
   $$
   \cases{x=1\\2x=2}
   $$
   has a solution.
3. $m=n$: yes, $Ax=0$ has a solution $x=0$.